# Php PDF creator - only create one page instead of multiple

Tags: php, pdf

I am using tcpdf to create pdf documents, based on data from my database. I am attempting to generate contracts from my clients based on their info. The pdf works, but only creates a contract for the first client in the database instead of a page for each of them.

Here is my code (simplified):

```
<?php
//This file create a pd contract agreement based on the client's detail. 

// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
require_once('connect.php');
$stmm= $conn->prepare("SELECT fields from table
WHERE MyConditions");
$stmm->execute();

while($resultst = $stmm-> fetch()){
  //list of myvariables to use is here



// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

//     set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Mycompany');
$pdf->SetTitle('Client Agreement');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' ', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

/*
NOTES:
 - To create self-signed signature: openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.crt
 - To export crt to p12: openssl pkcs12 -export -in tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.p12
 - To convert pfx certificate to pem: openssl pkcs12 -in tcpdf.pfx -out tcpdf.crt -nodes
*/    

// set certificate file
$certificate = 'file://data/cert/tcpdf.crt';

// set additional information
$info = array(
'Name' => 'My info',
'Location' => 'SA',
'Reason' => 'Advertising Agreement',
'ContactInfo' => 'http://www.mydomain.co.za',
)    ;

// set document signature
$pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'tcpdfdemo', '', 2, $info);

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 7);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// print a line of text
$text = "PDF layout for each client with their detail here as per SELECT query";
$pdf->writeHTML($text, true, 0, true, 0);


// define active area for signature appearance
$pdf->setSignatureAppearance(180, 60, 15, 15);


// *** set an empty signature appearance ***
$pdf->addEmptySignatureAppearance(180, 80, 15, 15);


//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('client_contracts.pdf', 'D');


//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
}
```

Any Idead

Comment: _"but only creates a contract for the first client in the database instead of a page for each of them"_ - well that might have to do with that you are creating a new TCPDF object _inside_ your loop on each iteration, don’t you think?

Comment: @CBroe - I have moved the loop all over to test, with the same result. But thanks for your comment

Comment: And the output part belongs _after_ the loop. Show us your updated code in the question.

Comment: Can you provide code to what you think might be the correct answer? As I said, I have tested the loop all over.

Comment: @CBroe ... Thanks. I have missed the loop where is should be after the new object. That sorted my issue

Comment: If you want 1 pdf file for each customer, you must change the name in the output. If you want ONE file with one page for each customer, you must put the "new TCPDF and all configuration before the loop and the "output" AFTER the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but only creates a contract for the first client in the database instead of a page for each of them

Well that would have to do with that you are creating a new TCPDF object inside your loop on each iteration.

Plus you are calling its output method inside your loop as well - both of those actions should be placed *outside* the loop.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. Sorted